# LFR Graph in R for Twitter analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, benchmarking

I created a Twitter mention (@) network in R with over 600.000 nodes (users).

My goal is to identify different communities in the established network.

For this, I want to benchmark clustering algorithms using a synthetic LFR graph with known ground truth and then single score quality indices.

The netUtils package in R can create synthetic LFR graphs. However, I need an LFR graph with over 600.000 nodes and this takes forever to compute / does not work reliable. All papers I have found so far, did not create such a big synthetic graph for testing their algorithms.

Is there a way to create such a big LFR graph (in a reasonable time)?
Or is there a better way to approach this task?

There are graphs online available for download. However, they only have around 20k nodes.

Thanks in advance.

I used the netutils package in R with different parameters which should recreate my original Twitter network. However, the sample_lfr function from netUtils takes forever.